# hjust not working properly to center my title in ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to R. I am having issues centering my title in `ggplot` using `hjust` and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is my following code and bar plot. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
ggplot(mentalsum, aes(x=task, y=mental, fill = task)) + 
  ggtitle( "NASA-TLX Mental Demand") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mental, ymax=mental+se),
                width=.2,                    # Width of the error bars
                position=position_dodge(.9)) + xlab("Task") + 
  ylab("Weighted Ratings") + 
  labs(fill= ("")) + 
  theme_classic()
```

Best,

Chris

[image]

Comment: Try without the theme_classic() function at the end of your code

Comment: .. or put `+ theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))` at the end.

Comment: @kanimbla  Wow, thanks so much. When I put the theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) at the end and put the theme_classic() line after the geom_error bar line, the title centered. Don't understand why this made a difference, but thanks so much for your help. I spent the last 1.5 hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: @markus Thanks for your recommendation. The code is now working.

Comment: @Chris Glad it worked. The reason is that `theme_classic()` overwrites the call to `theme(plot.title = ...)`